# Excel 2002 Add-In not loading when the application opens

Tags: vba, excel, add-in, excel-2002

Good afternoon,

I created an Excel .xla addin for Excel 2002.  This weird behavior I am seeing from it happens only on my machine, but not on my coworkers.  I would like to understand why.

The add-in has a UDF function that gets called from many, many spreadsheets.

- My Add-in is set to open when Excel opens.  When I open a blank spreadsheet it works fine.
- If I double-click on an .XLS that references the add-in, Excel fails to load the VBA project, and I get #NAME!.  However, if I open Excel and then the spreadsheet, it works fine.

I've checked the blacklist "disabled items" under the help menu.  There's nothing there.  This has been working for a long time now; I can't find out what changed.  I've tried nuking all Registry entries with my add-in's name and trying again.  Still doesn't work.

Any ideas?  Thanks.
-Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I figured out that all the problematic spreadsheets had RTD/DDE links in them, and it turns out that the data source process is never really running on my machine.  As soon as I went to Edit-Links and removed those links everything worked fine.